# Creating a page on Drupal with different header and footer

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I am a WordPress dev and I've been asked add a new page to a Drupal site by a friend of mine. The version is 7.56.

This is a login page and its header/footer have to be different from the rest of the site.

I have the HTML/CSS code for the entire page and this has to be added in.

I have added the login forms and those are styled accordingly. Now how to I replace the header and footer?

If this was wordpress I'd create a new template file and remove calls to `get_header()` and `get_footer()`, how do I do the same with Drupal?

Answer (score 2):

Create a file for your login page to customize it(put it in your theme directory). its template default name is `page--user--login.tpl.php` .( simpler solution is to  duplicate page.tpl.php file, and rename it to `page--user--login.tpl.php` and customize markup)

then create  two files

`login-header.inc`
`login-footer.inc`

put your markups there

then  just `include_once('login-header.inc')` and `include_once('login-footer.inc')`

don't forget, clear the cache to it applied.